# Generate a primary key on index view using T SQL

Tags: sql-server

I try to create an index view, and unique clustered index on the view. My problem is that how to generate a primary key within a select clause. E.g.

```
Create view ssrs.vMyView
with schemabinding
as
  select firstname, lastname, other columns  --example columns
  from mytable
```

how to generate a primary key for each row on the fly?

**Update**

The problem is that it does NOT have unique columns or combination of columns, so I need to generate a unique id on the fly. **Firstname and lastname are just example.** There are primary key for the base table.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Pingpong, firstname and lastname are a primary key? ouch! just scan the phone book, that isn't that a very unique primary key.  On top of that, it will cause lots of grief when someone gets married or divorced and wants to change their name.

Answer (score 7):

Once you've created this view, if you obeyed [all the rules and requirements for an indexed view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx), you should be able to just create the clustered index like this:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX cix_vMyView ON dbo.vMyView(....)
```

You need to choose a good, valid clustering key - preferably according to the NUSE principle:

- narrow
- unique
- static
- ever-increasing

An `INT IDENTITY` would be perfect - or something like a BIGINT or a combination of INT and DATETIME.

**Update:** seeing that your base table doesn't even have a primary key (**THAT's a much bigger problem** you'll need to fix ASAP!! *If it doesn't have a primary key, it's not a table*), you could use something like `ROW_NUMBER()` in your view definition:

```
CREATE VIEW ssrs.vMyView
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
  SELECT firstname, lastname,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Lastname, FirstName) AS 'ID'
  FROM dbo.mytable
```

to give you an "artificial" unique, ever-increasing primary key.

*(Update 2014-Apr-25: unfortunately, contrary to my belief at the time of posting this, this **won't work** since you cannot create a clustered index on a view that contains a ranking function like `ROW_NUMBER` .....). Thanks to @jspaey for pointing that out. So this makes it even more important to have a primary key on the base tables and include that in your view definition!)*

But again: if your base table **doesn't have a primary key** - fix that first !!

**Update #2:** ok, so your base table(s) **does** have a primary key after all - then why isn't that part of your view definition? I would **always** include all the primary keys from all base tables in my views - only those PK enable you to clearly identify rows from the base table, and they allow you to make your views updateable.

Comment: The problem is that it does NOT have unique columns, so I need to generate a unique id on the fly.

Comment: @Pingpong: add something that's unique ! I'm sure your base table has some kind of a primary key, no??

Comment: @Pingpong - You can (potentially) add `group by firstname, lastname` to the query and `COUNT_BIG(*)` to the `select` list to get rid of dupes then index `vMyView(firstname,lastname)`. Better to fix your base table though.

Comment: @Martin Smith, the firstname and lastname are just example. There are primary key for the base table.

Comment: @Pingpong - Well if your base table does have a primary key (contrary to what you said above) then include that in your view definition then.

Comment: You can't create an index on a view that uses ROW_NUMBER() or any other window ranking or aggregate function.

Comment: @jspaey: crap - you're right :-( Bummer ..... OK, so this makes it **even more** important to include something unique from the base tables in your views if you want to index them!

Answer (score 2):

Pingpong, Marc is right that you need something that is unique to add a primary key.  Remember that this does not need to be a single column, so if you have two columns that are unique together that would work perfectly well.

If no combination of columns is unique, you probably wish to rethink your view or even add columns so that there is something unique.

As a related note, remember that Enterprise edition will take advantage of indexed views automatically.  But outside of Enterprise Edition, you may need to explicitly tell the optimizer to use the index through the noexpand hint.  I wrote about that previous at [On Indexes and Views](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Indexed+Views/63963/)

Comment: the firstname and lastname are just example. There are primary key for the base table.

Comment: On which planet is 'Firstname + Lastname' a primary key? I guess it would be a planet where two people can't have the same name or they get fried by some kind of alien laser. Firstname + Lastname can very rarely be a primary key! (PS. I I realize Timothy's answer points out that picking something unique is the 'key' and it wasn't him that said this)